# How to avoid re-rendering with react-swipe library and useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, swipe

I am using a react library for swiping: https://github.com/voronianski/react-swipe
Making it work is straight-forward:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactSwipe from 'react-swipe'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledBox = styled.div`
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
`

const Carousel = () => {
  let reactSwipeEl;

  const [position, setPosition] = useState(0)
  console.log('position', position)

  const swipeOptions = {
    continuous: false,
    transitionEnd() {
      setPosition(reactSwipeEl.getPos())
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactSwipe
        className="carousel"
        swipeOptions={swipeOptions}
        ref={el => (reactSwipeEl = el)}
      >
        <StyledBox>PANE 1</StyledBox>
        <StyledBox>PANE 2</StyledBox>
        <StyledBox>PANE 3</StyledBox>
      </ReactSwipe>
      <Circles>
        <Circle isActive={0 === position} />
        <Circle isActive={1 === position}/>
      </Circles>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel
```

The code that I added is the one related with useState. The library works fine, but every time I swipe, I use the callback transitionEnd, in order to update the position state. It is updated, but since a state variable changes, the whole Carousel component gets updated, setting automatically the init value, which is 0.

I don't understand how can I avoid this problem which is, updating the state without re-rendering the whole component. Should I split it in two components and use a provider? 
I tried it, but when the state of the provider changes, both components are also re-render

Comment: What are you going to the do with `position` besides logging it?

Comment: i have 4 circles, display a little bit bigger the circle corresponding to the slide, that's why I need to track the position of the slide. I tried to split components and use a provider & context, but everytime i touch the state, whole page gets re-render. not sure if library has this behaviour and i can't do nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `swipeOptions` is recreated on each render, which causes the `ReactSwipe` to rerender as well. Wrap the `swipeOptions` with `useMemo()` ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-rgb-sokv4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark));

```
const swipeOptions = useMemo(() => ({
  continuous: false,
  transitionEnd() {
    setPosition(reactSwipeEl.current.getPos())
  }
}), []);
```

Comment: Very react elegant solution, thanks a lot. I solved it though just doing this: startSlide: position in the swipeOptions. It worked. but your solution is better, since it works also using callback instead of transitionEnd. My solution using callback was very bumpy.